# how to make datatypes like this

Tags: javascript, function

If I run

```
"string".toUpperCase();
```

the code should return

```
STRING
```

how does this work, from what I know functions can only be called like this;

```
myFunction("args");
```

how would I make a function that is called the same way as `.toUpperCase()`

Comment: The method you are using exists on the `String` function's prototype. You need to read up on how prototypes and constructor functions work in JS. An example: `function Greeter (greeting) { this.greeting = greeting; }; Greeter.prototype.greet = function(name) { return this.greeting + " " + name + "!"; }`. Now you can do: `new Greeter("Hello").greet("chaps")` and obtain `"Hello chaps!"`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a [reference](http://devdocs.io/javascript/classes).

The format is like `Class.method()`.

On your example `"string".toUpperCase();`, the "string" is wrapped by the `String` Class :) since it is a *[primitive](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Primitive)*.

`.method()` is what they sometimes call **function**.

Actually, on the browser, when you define something like:

```
function happy(){
    console.log("learning");
}
```

and you called it like `happy()`, it is equivalent to `window.happy()`. Try it on you web console to validate.

Here is the example from the reference given above.

```
class Rectangle {
  constructor(height, width) {
    this.height = height;
    this.width = width;
  }

  get area() {
    return this.calcArea();
  }

  calcArea() {
    return this.height * this.width;
  }
}

const square = new Rectangle(10, 10);

console.log(square.area);
```

Comment: _the "string" is an instance of the String Class_ Mm. Not quite. `"string" instanceof String` is `false`. Don't confuse primitives and their wrapper objects. (`new String("string")` !== `String("string")`).

Comment: @bowheart wow, thanks for that. So the `wrapper` is used to access the `primitives`?

Comment: Could you suggest how to say it then? :)

Comment: The primitive is usually used to access the wrapper. But you can create a wrapper explicitly and use `wrapper.valueOf()` to get the underlying primitive (e.g. `new String("string").valueOf()`).

Comment: Sure, you'd just say _"string" is a string primitive wrapped by the `String` object_. To be technical, primitives have no properties or methods, but JavaScript will coerce the primitive to its wrapper object temporarily when necessary (e.g. `"string".toUpperCase()`  creates a string primitive, coerces it to its wrapper object, and accesses the `.toUpperCase()` method on that object which returns a new string primitive).

Answer (score 1):

You can store a function directly on an object.

```
let foo = {
  bar() {

  }
};

foo.bar()
```

Or you can store one indirectly on an object's prototype.

```
String.prototype.bar = function() {
  return "my " + this;
}

let foo = "string";
foo.bar(); // "my string"
```

Adding methods to existing prototypes (monkey patching) is generally considered to be a bad idea, but defining new prototypes with methods is often used when implementing prototypal inheritance.

```
function Vehicle() {
  this.fuel = 100;
}

Vehicle.prototype.drive = () => {
  this.fuel -= 1;
}

let car = new Vehicle();
let train = new Vehicle();

car.drive();
train.drive();
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is your solution;

```
String.prototype.myfunction = function () {
  return this.toUpperCase();
}

>>> "hello".myfunction()
"HELLO"
```

Comment: no, i mean creating a function that when called is called in the way something like str.toUpperCase is handled, having a `arg.myfunction` not `myfunction(arg)`